# How can I combine two csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

How can i combine 2 csv files. My data is the following:

**first csv file:**

Organization  Address   Country

The Thief   Landgangen  Norway

The Thief   Landgangen  World

The Thief   Landgangen  Norway

**Second csv file:**

Location                Rating Date Rating

College Station  Texas  3 days ago  5

Cork  Ireland           3 days ago  5

Oslo  Oslo  Norway      3 days ago  5

If the columns or the rows are not the same in the above files what should I do?

Thanks for your help

TA

Comment: You probably should not merge them.

Comment: Do you want to combine them by row or by column? Also, what is your goal in combining them? Without that knowledge, it's hard to tell what you "should do".

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
  You need to try yourself first, SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

To combine CSV there must be something unique in both the CSV.

Below is sample code using pandas module. Make the required changes as per your requirement.

To deal with large amount of data, I prefer pandas(pandas process the data very fast and easy to use)

```
import pandas as pd
#read CSV1
CSV1 = pd.read_csv(filename=csv1.csv, delimiter=",")#Skip rows if required, skiprows=2)
#read CSV2
CSV2 = pd.read_csv(filename=csv2.csv, delimiter=",")#Skip rows if required, skiprows=2)
#Combine CSV
CombinedCSV = pd.merge(CSV1, CSV2, left_on=['Unique'], right_on=['Unique'], how='left')
#Save the CSV
CombinedCSV.to_csv('CombinedCSV .csv', sep=',', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```